# Why is this else statement not triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get a div to get behind another div on one click and on top of the div on the next click. So for example when div1 is behind div2 and you click div1 it should appear in front of div2. When you click div1 again (which is now in front of div2) it should get behind div2 again.

I'm trying to look up the z-index of the div and decide wether the the z-index should be higher or lower with an if/else statement. But for some reason the else isn't being triggered, it only seems to run the if statement.

[The jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/126tm0e0/5/)

The code below is where I'm trying to look up whether the z-index is lower or higher then 5 (they can only be 0 or 10 but this seemed like a good foolproof method to do the check). The problem is that even when the z-index is turned into 10 that the ifstatement is still getting executed instead of the else.

```
if ($(".div1").css("z-index") < "5") { //is z-index smaller then 5? make it 10
   $(".div1").click(function() {
      $(this).css('z-index', '10');
      console.log('block1 if');
   });
} else { //is z-index bigger then 5? make it 0
   $(".div1").click(function() {
      $(this).css('z-index', '0');
      console.log('block1 else');
});
}
```

I'm totally lost as to what the problem is so all help is welcome.
And thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: take your **$(".div1").css("z-index")** and console.log it out, make sure you're getting what you expect. Also, "5" is a string, do you need an integer?

Comment: Because "10" is smaller than "5".

Comment: Ai... that was a stupid mistake, but even if I change "5" to 5 the else is still not triggered

Comment: @HagelslagBMB: The `else` isn't triggered because the one time that it's evaluated, when the page loads, the `if` resolves to `true`.  The `if` condition in this code is only ever evaluated once, when the page loads, and then never again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this fixes your problem, but i think you should move your if/else inside a single click event. Also like other people stated, you need to compare to an int and not a string

```
  $(".div1").click(function() {
      if ($(this).css("z-index") < 5)
      {
        $(this).css('z-index', '10');
      }
      else{
        $(this).css('z-index', '0');
      }
      console.log($(this).css('z-index'));
   });
```

Comment: This does fix the problem, thank you very much! And yeah I'm a little ashamed that I overlooked the int to string comparison.

Comment: The if condition should use `this`.

Comment: @nnnnnn True, copied it from the question, updated now

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement compares strings, not numbers... here is how they should look.

```
if (parseInt($(".div1").css("z-index")) < 5) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings:

```
if (parseInt($(".div1").css("z-index")) < 5) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You're always setting the z-index to the same static values, regardless of what they are when the element is clicked.  Look at your click handler:

```
$(".div1").click(function() {
   $(this).css('z-index', '10');
   console.log('block1 if');
});
```

So any time `.div1` is clicked, its z-index will *always* be statically set to `'10'`.  I suspect you meant to compare *inside* the click handlers:

```
$('.div1').click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('z-index') < '5') {
        $(this).css('z-index', '10');
        console.log('block1 if');
    } else {
        $(this).css('z-index', '0');
        console.log('block1 else');
    }
});
```

---

In addition, you're comparing *strings* instead of *numbers*.  For reference, `"10"` is actually *less than* `"5"`.  However, `10` is greater than `5`.  You may want to compare numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code, I would upvote it if I had the rep to do so. By the way, if I need to compare int's shouldn't '5' just be 5 without any quotes?

Comment: @HagelslagBMB: Unless something's changed, I thought users could always upvote answers on their own questions.  Regardless, that's not particularly important.  As for comparing numbers, correct, you'd remove the quotes from the literal value.

Comment: Seems like something has changed then because I need 15 rep to be able to vote an answer as useful. But you have my gratitude either way.

Comment: @HagelslagBMB: Well you'll be there soon enough I'm sure.  Glad we could help, and good luck with your continued coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happen because of you compare Int to String.

Example :

If you `css` is `z-index:10` and you compare it with `"5"` then its mean you compare int to string.

`like this 10 < "5"`

This's reason why your else condition not trigger

Answer (score 0):

**Better Approach**

***Javascript code***

```
  $(".zIndex").click(function() {       
    if($(this).css('z-index') > 0){         
        $(".zIndex").css('z-index', '10');                
        $(this).css('z-index', '0');
  }
  else{
        $(".zIndex").css('z-index', '0');
        $(this).css('z-index', '10');        
  }
});
```

***HTML***

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="zIndex div1" style="z-index: 0;">A</div>
  <div class="zIndex div2" style="z-index: 0;">B</div>
  <div class="zIndex div3" style="z-index: 0;">C</div>
```

Comment: From the question: "When you click div1 again (which is now in front of div2) it should get behind div2 again."

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn. I have updated my post https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/126tm0e0/7/